# AWS cloudwatch schedule drops event, calling second lambda in eventbridge

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cron, amazon-sqs, amazon-cloudwatch

I have been trying to address the issue (dropping an event in a queue with “cron") and need to get someone else’s insight on the issue.

**Current status:**
Currently, I have two lambdas. The thing that I am trying to do is to set the schedule (cloudwatch - every 12PM) to trigger the Lambda A, and the Lambda A triggers Lambda B via Event bridge.

It is all working if I use schedule-expression as "cron(0/5 * * * ? *)" which means it triggers the Lambda A every 5 mins and I can get the end result from Lambda B.

Since the 5 mins interval is working with the whole flow (CloudWatch schedule -> Lambda A -> Lambda B), I can tell all the rules and event bridge setting etc are working.

**Problem:**
The problem is that when I change the Schedule expression to cron(0 12 * * ? *) from cron(0/5 * * * ? *), it only worked until Lambda A - which means the “cron" triggers the Lambda A at 12PM correctly but the following event to trigger the Lambda B is not working for some reason.

The event on SQS (calling Lambda B) is dropped and put it to Deadletter queue.

**I have tried:**
I have compared the event(calling Lambda B) detail between using cron 12PM and 5mins interval expressions and no differences found.

I have checked UTC now(let's say this moment is 1am), then I have set cron(5 1 * * ? *), but it only calls the Lambda A.

I have checked the individual Lambdas and event bridge and setting. It worked fine individually.

I have used rate(5mins) instead of cron without any other changes, the Lambda B got correctly triggered.

**Questions:**
I would like to know what could be the cause of this issue and what could be a way to get proper logs for it.

Please let me know if you have any thought or ideas on this issue.